# Syntax for including the 'AND' logical operator in IF statements

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I've been trying to use an 'AND' logical operator in my IF statement. The syntax I've been using is IF(statement1*statement2.....)

**Main Question:** Is using '*' the correct approach towards using the and logical operator for if statements? What is

**Logic of if statement below:** *IF date in cell1 < date today AND cell2 is not blank THEN show the month of cell 1. If not, output 0.*

```
=IF('[COPY 2015 Quality Log_NCR.xlsx]NCR 2015'!$S2<TODAY()*(NOT(ISBLANK('[COPY 2015 Quality Log_NCR.xlsx]NCR 2015'!$V$2))),MONTH('[COPY 2015 Quality Log_NCR.xlsx]NCR 2015'!$S2),0)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Correct syntax for your Logic is:

```
=IF(AND(Sheet1!$S2<TODAY(),(NOT(ISBLANK(Sheet1!$V$2)))),MONTH(Sheet1!$S2),0)
```

You need to do `AND(criterion1, criterion2)`

- I replaced your "[COPY 2015 Quality Log_NCR.xlsx]NCR 2015" sheet name with "Sheet1" to make the formula readable

Answer (score 1):

The `*` operator will work as long as you are using it on boolean values, because it simply treats them as a 1 or 0 and multiplies them.

The result of this operation will either be a 1 or 0, which are treated as True or False in the condition input of the IF statement.

You can also use the `AND()` function.

The following evaluate the same

```
AND(TRUE,FALSE) = AND(1,0) = TRUE * FALSE = 1 * 0 = 0 = FALSE
```

The following evaluate the same

```
AND(1<2,3<4) = (1<2)*(3<4) = 1 * 1 = 1 = TRUE
```